# Homework Logic Error. Strange if statement

Tags: java

I'm a college freshman with a java logic error. For this assignment the user should enter 1 or 2 to identify whether to go from pounds to kilograms or kilograms to pounds (ConversionStatus). Whenever I run the program and input 1 or 2 I get my error message "Invalid Response, Program Closing".

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Declarations
double Weight, Pounds, Kilograms;
double ConversionStatus;

// Print Convert weights prompt
System.out.println("Convert Weights: ");
System.out.println("Pounds to Kilograms (enter 1)");
System.out.println("Kilograms to pounds (enter 2)");
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.print("Which conversion do you want? ");
ConversionStatus = input.nextInt();
// If ConversionStatus isnt 1 or 2, print "Invalid response, please restart program"
if (ConversionStatus != 1 || ConversionStatus != 2)
{
  System.out.println("Invalid Response, Program Closing");
  System.exit(3);
}
System.out.print("What weight value do you want converted? ");
Weight = input.nextInt();


// Pounds to Kilograms Program if ConversionStatus=1
if (ConversionStatus == 1)
{
  Pounds = Weight;
  Kilograms = Pounds / 2.2;
  System.out.println(Pounds + "converted to kilograms is: " + Kilograms);
}
```

Comment: if (ConversionStatus!=1 && ConversionStatus!=2)

Comment: Also, consider using an integer for `ConversionStatus` as i doubt you expect the user to enter 1.5 there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will *always* be true:

```
if (ConversionStatus!=1 || ConversionStatus!=2)
```

Because the same value can never *simultaneously* equal *both* 1 and 2.  So at least one of those two statements must be true.

It sounds like you want to invoke this code only if *both* parts are true, not just one of them:

```
if (ConversionStatus!=1 && ConversionStatus!=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I understand my error. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

`if (ConversionStatus!=1 || ConversionStatus!=2){`

Think about this. What if `ConversionStatus == 1`? Then at the same time, `ConversionStatus != 2` so the program will exit.

You want to use the `&&` operator, not `||`.